# C#, not sure how to work with this Json deserialization

Tags: c#, json, ibm-watson

Long and short, I'm trying to take the results from a speech to text call to IBM's Watson, and get the final transcription itself into plain text. The output of the transcription ends up being a mess of Json in this format,

```
{
  "result_index": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "final": true,
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "%HESITATION %HESITATION %HESITATION %HESITATION %HESITATION it is probably is actual words okay what's my best ",
          "confidence": 0.74
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which when run through a JSON to C# Converter, leads to something like this

```
    public class Alternative
    {
        public string transcript { get; set; }
        public double confidence { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public bool final { get; set; }
        public List<Alternative> alternatives { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public int result_index { get; set; }
        public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    }
```

Ultimately, I just want to get to that transcript under alternative and send it to a text box, however I cannot for the life of me get that working, here's about as far as I get, with no idea on where to go from here to get to that transcript.

```
                var bAudio = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
                var memAudio = new MemoryStream(bAudio);
                var results1 = speechToText.Recognize(memAudio, model: "en-US_NarrowbandModel");
                Root resultsTranscription = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(results1.Response);
```

I ultimately get 0 output. I can't seem to comprehend exactly how this is breaking down the JSON into it's various components

Comment: resultsTranscription.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript

Comment: Yep, that solved it, and now I actually understand a bit of how this works, lol. Thank's @Chetan

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make your C# break its own naming conventions and follow the JSON:

```
public class Alternative
{
    [JsonProperty("transcript")]
    public string Transcript { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("confidence")]
    public double Confidence { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("final")]
    public bool Final { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("alternatives")]
    public List<Alternative> Alternatives { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("result_index")]
    public int ResultIndex { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Use a more sophisticated website, like https://QuickType.iO (no affiliation) to convert your JSON and it will fill in for you these properties that specify one name for the json and another for the csharp

You can also stream from a file, which would save memory; there's no need to load a file into a memory stream just to get a stream (well, unless Recognize really does take a MemoryStream; most stream based things take a simple Stream so they can be sourced from anything that's provided a stream of data; memory, file, network):

```
using var audioStream = File.OpenRead(file);
var results1 = speechToText.Recognize(audioStream, model: "en-US_NarrowbandModel");
 var resultsTranscription = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(results1.Response);
```

Then you can use normal indexed or linq style access:

```
resultsTranscription.Results[0].Alternatives[0].Transcript;

resultsTranscription.Results.First().Alternatives.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Confidence > 0.7)?.Transcript;
```

The latter form gets the first wording whose confidence is above 70%, for example..